# Spikes in Tensorboard logs - PPO2 Stable Baselines

Tags: python, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Python3.7 - Tensorflow 1.14.0

I'm running a custom gym environment using the [stable baseline PPO2 model](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html), with MlpLstmPolicy as policy.

After training the model I had a look at the Tensorboard logs.
On both Input and Loss tabs you can clearly see Spikes all-over the charts

[image: Tesorboard logs - Scalars tab - Input]

[image: Tesorboard logs - Scalars tab - Loss]

This is a close up of the 
[image: Loss chart]

Does anyone know why this is happening, is it because of the datasets, because of the hyper parameters, or because of the environment?

I know its a very broad question, hope someone can help...

Let me know if I can help by providing more specific info

Answer (score 0):

I guess with this much information it is really difficult to say what is happening. I am also training some collision avoidance models for the past couple of months. From my experience I think it is normal to get spikes in your training. I think the only thing that matters is after smoothing the overall reward should be increasing. In my case, I am getting spikes as I am training multiple agents parallelly for some agents the task at hand is really difficult and they mostly don't accumulate many rewards also initially exploration probability is high so that might be the reason that you are getting spikes.

Comment: I agree that that is certainly one such case. There are, unfortunately, many more. Perhaps the original question poster can add some more detail because numerical instabilities can occur for many reasons.Utsav gave one common one, which is helpful. Another one may be the sensitivity of the numerical convergence rate to the input data range, and so on.